# Defined ABSPATH doesn't work in different directory

Tags: php

So, I'm having a bit of an issue with a defined directory in my PHP--included below.

```
<?php
/* 
TODO: 
    -Everything
*/
if(!defined("ABSPATH"))
{
    define("ABSPATH", dirname(__DIR__)."/");
}
include(ABSPATH.'/lib/config.php');
require_once(ABSPATH."/lib/db.php");
?>
```

THe issue I'm having is, once I try to include it in a different directory, the `ABSPATH` apparently stops working. As the config file and the db file are not loading. Which of course makes the entire page not load, which is an issue.

The Directory I'm loading is from *root/directory_1* .

Comment: The `__DIR__` returns the directory of the currently loaded file, not that of the first script that runs as part of a web request.

Comment: @Jenz what do you mean with "apparently stops working"? if You echo ABSPATH what do you see in both case?

Comment: what is expected path for include file and also show your dir structure

Comment: @Jack, I understand this. The file I'm loading (The one whose code is included above) is in the location of the rest of the files.

Comment: @gafreax..I am not the author of this question..

Comment: I tested your code and couldn't replicate the problem. It was successful for me. You could try removing all closing `?>` tags in all your files, but I doubt that would do any good. Check to see if you have anything in `.htaccess` that could affect this, including your other config and db files. @user3462020